# How can I secure lambda functions with a cognito user pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Originally asked: What is the pure javascript or curl solution to get a cognito identity pool token using a user pool token?  But question clarification led us in a different direction.  Editing to make this question/answer easy to follow.

I am currently prototyping, and I have a working pure javascript solution to login from a website and obtain a cognito user pool token.  How can I access lambdas using this token?

I setup my lambdas with serverless framework to use a cognito user pool

```
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: get
          authorizer:
            name: authorizer
            arn: arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-2:12345:userpool/us-east-2_UvCsU4UcR
```

This automatically creates an API gateway authorizer and associates it with the endpoint.

Solution:

Working with @Quassnoi, I discovered I was using the wrong token when accessing the lambdas.  The object that comes back from POSTing to:

<YOUR_COGNITO>.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oath2/token

contains an id_token, and an access_token.  If you grab the id_token and paste it into curl as specified in the solution, you can access the secured lambda, with no other configuration required other than the 3 lines to your serverless configuration.

Comment: Can you clarify what API gateway has got to do with this? And then subsqequently, what does curl or JS have to do with APUGW? What is your expected input, expected output, and what you've tried? What's the overall problem here?

Comment: The overall goal is authorization staying in my IaC (terraform and serverless framework) and not polluting my source code

Comment: Due to clarifying the question, @Quassnoi has pushed towards a solution that doesn't match the original question.  Reviewing some questions in Meta, it seems like it won't be an issue if I edit the question to better fit the answer once we figure out exactly what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It looks like there is a different way to directly specify a user pool for authentication

That's exactly how I would use it. You don't need an identity pool for that.

I'm assuming you know how to create a user pool on cognito and exchange your credentials for a token.

1. Set up the Authorizer on your API Gateway. I'm not sure how to do that on Serverless, but on Terraform you would use something like this:

   ```
   resource "aws_api_gateway_authorizer" "hello" {
       name                   = "demo"
       rest_api_id            = "myapiid"
       type                   = "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
       provider_arns          = ["arn:aws:cognito-idp:{region}:{account_id}:userpool/{user_pool_id}"]
   }
   ```

   By default, this will use `Authorization` header for the identity source, you will see it in the console.
2. In the Resource definition of your API Gateway, set up your authorizer:

   ```
   resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "hello_get" {
     rest_api_id          = "myapiid"
     resource_id          = "myapiid.hello.id"
     http_method          = "GET"
     authorization        = "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
     authorizer_id        = aws_api_gateway_authorizer.hello.id
     authorization_scopes = ["my.authorization.scope"]

     # Lambda integration setup here
   }
   ```
3. Deploy and pass the id token from your User Pool in the request:

   ```
   curl -H "Authorization: Bearer [id-token]" https://my-gateway-url.example.com/stage/hello
   ```

That's it!

If your token has `my.authorization.scope` in its `scope` claim, the request will get authorized and passed to the Lambda handle.

All the information from JWT will get passed to the integration in  the variable `$event.requestContext.authorizer.jwt` assessible within the mapping template.

You're free to use it in a mapping and pass it to the Lambda code, should you want to.

Comment: Your proposed solution seems like the way to go.  It looks like serverless automatically creates an authorizer and adds it to the lambda if I use the code as pasted above in Edit 2.  But I am not having success accessing the lambda.  Do you know how the token should be passed into the lambda?

Comment: @lopass: I've updated the post. What does exactly "success accessing the lambda" mean? Is it not being called, or not being passed parameters, or is not returning a response?

Comment: if you look at Edit 1 in my original post, I tried passing the token in the headers previously.  I tried again just now, and I always get: {"message":"Unauthorized"}.  I assume the base64 token is the JWT token returned from authorization.  I noticed the scopes created by serverless is empty, does it need to match the token exactly or at least contain one matching scope?

Comment: @lopass: Cognito will return you a whole bunch of tokens, make sure you're using `IdToken`. If you leave the scopes empty in the method properties, any token issued by this pool will work. Don't forget the `Bearer` part when you fill in the header.

Comment: @lopass: also I'm not sure if serverless does that, but every time you change resources on the API Gateway, you need to deploy your changes to the stage. Make sure it's been done.

Comment: that was the issue, I was getting the access_token, not the id_token.  I am going to make some edits to the question and mark this as the correct answer.  Thanks for your help.